# Android chartboost cocos2d-x integration

Tags: cocos2d-x, chartboost

I am using wenbin1988 tutorial [chartboost cocos2d-x integration] for my project.
I managed to get the project ready for ios and android.
The chartboost works fine in ios but has problem in android.
In android the chartboost is called but has no window opened and no advertisement displayed.
The error mentioned in eclipse is

02-22 19:35:44.520: D/PhoneWindow(18143): couldn't save which view has focus because the focused view org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView@463440b0 has no id.

Can anyone please help to resolve the issue
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In their help with sdk implementation they say that in Android, if you are using OpenGL (the case of cocos2d-x) you need to set:

```
cb.setImpressionsUseActivities(true);
```

And after setting this you will need to put the below code on the AndroidManifest as well:

```
<activity android:name="com.chartboost.sdk.CBImpressionActivity"
    android:excludeFromRecents="true"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"/>
```

Hope this helps.